# Nativescript app - nativescript-toast plugin - Failed to find module:

Tags: toast, nativescript-angular

When using the nativescript-toast plugin, my app receives the error "Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "nativescript-toast", relative to: app/tns_modules/"

I created a new nativescript app.

I created a home component and made it the default route.

I installed the "n[ativescript-toast](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-toast)" plugin.

I added a button to the home component's html, with a tap event that calls the showToast() method in the component typescript file.

Here is the code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Toast from 'nativescript-toast';

@Component({
  selector: 'ns-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  moduleId: module.id,
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  showToast() {
    const toast = Toast.makeText('Hello');
    toast.show();
  }

}
```

I tried previewing the app on my device via "tns preview" and scanning the barcode.

Then, it immediately fails with the error mentioned.

If I comment the lines in the showToast() method the app renders.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell from you package.json which version of nativescript-toast are you using?

Comment: version "nativescript-toast": "^2.0.0"

Comment: that should work. is it possible for you to create a playground?

Comment: Actually I just realised you can't make a playground. It says "Plugins which have native dependencies are not supported in the Playground. To use such plugins, configure your environment for local NativeScript development."

Comment: Did you manage to fix that?

Comment: Not yet.  Very frustrating.